# how can play video with full volume sound in html

Tags: html

this is my html code, its work but with no sound!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style>

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

</style>



    </head>

    <body>
    <video  autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" >
      <source src="https://4.top4top.net/m_1348rq2js1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    </body>

    </html>
```

i want it play with full sound volume and full screen
can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: You need to remove `muted` from the video tag in order to play the audio. As for full-screen, a browser will block automatic full-screen videos. There has to be some sort of user action that triggers the full-screen.

Comment: when i remove muted  still with no sound at all

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome? If so you might want to take a look at auto play policies. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes